# Popup verify native password android

Tags: android

I want the user type is password and press the Ok button, and then will be a check whether this really is the device's password. if it is so the app will be close and if not pop up try again.

```
  new MaterialDialog.Builder(Finished.this)
                    .title("To exit enter your phone password")
                    .inputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD)
                    .positiveText(R.string.ok)
                    .negativeText(R.string.cancle)
                    .input(R.string.input_hint, Integer.parseInt(""), new MaterialDialog.InputCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onInput(MaterialDialog dialog, CharSequence input) {
                            // Do something
                        }
                    })
                    .callback(new MaterialDialog.ButtonCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPositive(MaterialDialog dialog) {
                            onBackPressed();
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For obvious security reasons, ordinary Apps are not permitted to check values against the device password.

In API level 21, there is a new method [KeyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html) which returns an Intent to you. You can then call `startActivityForResult` with this Intent to confirm the device password.

> Added in API level 21.
>
> Get an intent to prompt the user to confirm
>   credentials (pin, pattern or password) for the current user of the
>   device. The caller is expected to launch this activity using
>   startActivityForResult(Intent, int) and check for RESULT_OK if the
>   user successfully completes the challenge.
>
> Returns the intent for launching the activity or null if no password
>   is required.

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {

  public static final int REQUEST_PWD_PROMPT = 1;

  void promptForDevicePassword() {
     // get an instance of the KeyguardManager
     KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) this.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
     // get the intent to prompt the user
     Intent intent = km.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent("My App Name", "Enter your password to exit this App.");

     // launch the intent
     startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PWD_PROMPT);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
      // see if this is being called from our password request..?
      if (requestCode == REQUEST_PWD_PROMPT) {
          // ..it is. Did the user get the password right?
          if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // they got it right
          } else {
            // they got it wrong/cancelled
          }
      }
  }


}
```

Comment: cen you give me Pseudo code ? 
or some code for example?

Comment: I cent use the 22 api level  I am using the 15

Comment: @gal You will not be able to do this before API level 21 - Apps simply don't have permission to test values against the device password. You could try explaining in your question what you are trying to achieve and *why* you need to check the device password - someone might have a better solution to your problem.