# How can I ask the user to enter their passcode before opening an activity?

Tags: android, passwords

I want to achieve something like when the user tries to open a certain activity, I want to show them a system lock screen, where they can enter their device passcode and then open a new activity.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the documentation for Biometric Authentication, the examples there should be get you on the right track:
https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth

Answer (score 1):

@user3673952 's answer is for biometric access. For verifying on-device credentials, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32036437/popup-verify-native-password-android) helpful.